# Wierd Time format

Tags: time, format

i'm working with and API that gives some data parsed in JSON.

One of the field of the data that i recive is a date/time that have this format
e.g:

**2018-09-18T15:29:09.0528337Z**

I'm  trying to undestand the meaning of the last digits.

Any help?

Thaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) page on Wikipedia:

> Decimal fractions may be added to any of the three time elements. However, a fraction may only be added to the lowest order time element in the representation.

Those last digits are decimal fractions of a second<del>, in that case, microseconds</del> (**edit**: oops, not microseconds -- there are actually 7 digits).

`Z` denotes UTC timezone.

Comment: Ok, 7 digit of what?

Comment: Well, the API you're using gives you date/times with sub-second precision. Considering only the time element (ignoring the date), i.e. `15:29:09.0528337`, that's 15h, 29mn, 09s plus 0.0528337 second.